# polygon label displying duplicate in mapbox studio style editor

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I have uploaded polygon shape zip file in mapbox tileset and created layer name as polygon_label but layer labels are showing duplicate inside polygon area.
[image: duplicate polygon label]

So there is any way to centroid the polygon geometry or restrict to display duplicate label.

How to get label centroid of the polygon and remove duplication of the label from polygon area?

Comment: Please give some comment,other wise how to know what is the wrong in this question

Answer (score 3):

You need to create point geometries and use that as your source.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with a shapefile with land sections I imported. To get the outline of the land sections I added a fill type layer since the tileset contains polygon features. Then I add another layer of type symbol to be able to show the section address text field from the tileset features. I set the placement as "Point". But, the text field shows multiple places inside the polygons. [image: polygon features showing duplicate labels when placement set as point]

The only solution I have found is to make the labels appear along the boundries of the polygons by setting the placement as "Line". This still shows multiple labels. But, it is a bit more friendly for the user.
[image: Feature label with placement set as Line]